# Why won't my icon font icon stay rotated?

Tags: html, css, icon-fonts

I am trying to a rotate an icon with `transform: rotateZ(90deg)` but it seems like it is ignoring it.

When I add a transition to the icon I can see the animation of the icon rotating but then it snaps back into place when it is done animating.

Here it is:

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);

/* fontawesome */
[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}

span {
  transition: 2s;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 500px;
}

span:hover {
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="fontawesome-download-alt"></span>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because the `<span>` is an inline element, and inline elements are not "transformable."  Simply change it's `display` property to `inline-block`.

## from the W3C:

> ### transformable element
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories: an
>   element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either
>   a block-level or atomic inline-level element, or whose display
>   property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group,
>   table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption [CSS21]

According to the W3C, **inline elements are not listed as "transformable".**

## example

```css
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);

/* fontawesome */
[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}

span {
  transition: 2s;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 500px;
  display: block;
/* ^^ Change this */
}

span:hover {
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="fontawesome-download-alt"></span>
```

Comment: Is this in the spec somewhere? Can't find anything about it

Comment: Yes I know where the spec is. But where is it mentioned that inline elements revert to their original state after a transition?

Comment: hmmm...snippet still loads downside for me.

Comment: That's not the problem, @SurgeonofDeath.  When it was hovered, the animation refverted back to down.  Now it stays in place while hovered.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn, you can see in the above spec that `<span>` is not listed as a "transformable element."

Comment: That still wouldn't explain why it would transform and then revert back. The transition shouldn't happen at all. Edit: after testing it seems Firefox and Safari dont' trigger the transform, only Chrome

Comment: It's not supposed to happen.  It must be a chrome bug. @uʍopǝpısdn.

Comment: this is why people hate CSS

Answer (score 1):

Use DIV, not SPAN; set your width and height and add `display:block;`
Also, add `-webkit-transition: 2s;` and `-webkit-transform:rotateZ(90deg);` for it to work on all browsers. See below code.

```
<style>
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=fontawesome);

/* fontawesome */
[class*="fontawesome-"]:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', sans-serif;
}

div {
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
  transition: 2s;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 500px;
  display: block;
  width: 470px;
  height: 470px;
}

div:hover {
  -webkit-transform:rotateZ(90deg);
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
</style>

<div class="fontawesome-download-alt"></div>
```